# Select sequences of values from groups at random

Tags: r, dplyr, random

Here is the data:

```
df <-
  data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
             value = LETTERS[1:20])
```

I need to randomly select sequences of four values from each group with `dplyr`. Selected values should be in the same order as in the data, and there should be no gaps between them.

Desired result may look like this:

```
   group value
1      1     A
2      1     B
3      1     C
4      1     D
6      2     F
7      2     G
8      2     H
9      2     I
11     3     K
12     3     L
13     3     M
14     3     N
17     4     Q
18     4     R
19     4     S
20     4     T

   group value
1      1     A
2      1     B
3      1     C
4      1     D
5      2     E
6      2     F
7      2     G
8      2     H
10     3     J
11     3     K
12     3     L
13     3     M
17     4     Q
18     4     R
19     4     S
20     4     T
```

This is where I am in solving this:

```
set.seed(23)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(selected = sample(0:1, size = n(), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(selected == 1)
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to generate exactly 4 ones in a row, with zeroes before or after them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `sample` the number of rows (*minus three*) in the group, size one, and add `0:3` to that to select which rows we retain.

```r
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(sample(max(1, n()-3), size=1) + 0:3)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 2
#    group value
#    <dbl> <chr>
#  1     1 A    
#  2     1 B    
#  3     1 C    
#  4     1 D    
#  5     2 E    
#  6     2 F    
#  7     2 G    
#  8     2 H    
#  9     3 J    
# 10     3 K    
# 11     3 L    
# 12     3 M    
# 13     4 Q    
# 14     4 R    
# 15     4 S    
# 16     4 T
```

Safety steps here:

- `max(1, n()-3)` makes sure that we don't attempt to sample negative (or zero) row numbers
- if we have a group with fewer than 4 rows, this still works (selecting all rows) since `row_number() %in% ...` will never try to index rows that don't exist, even if `c(sample(.) + 0:3)` might *suggest* more rows than exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a bit with `embed` (but not as efficient as the [answer by @r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77715504/12158757))

```
df %>%
    filter(
        value %in% embed(value, 4)[sample.int(n() - 3, 1), ],
        .by = group
    )
```

or

```
df %>%
    summarise(
        value = list(embed(value, 4)[sample.int(n() - 3, 1), 4:1]),
        .by = group
    ) %>%
    unnest(value)
```